# Using string as a component name in <svelte:component>

Tags: svelte

Let's say we have a custom component in Svelte created using the dynamic special tag. And let's say we have a **string** with the name of the component constructor.

```js
<script>
    import testComponent from './Something.svelte';

    let componentConstructorName = 'testComponent';
</script>

<svelte:component this="{componentConstructorName}" />
```

Is it possible to parse the component constructor name and render the corresponding component directly in the `this` property?

I am aware I could create an object that assigns the constructor references to it's string names, but I am trying to do this in more automated way without doing any manual assignments.

The following will work, but I do feel some pain using `eval()`.

```js
<svelte:component this="{ eval(componentConstructorName) }" />
```

Comment: Being tracked here: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2324

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not directly possible to do so, you will have to go somehow from the string to the constructor reference.  But instead of the `eval` which is not really recommended, you can use a second, reactive, variable:

```js
let componentContructorName = 'testComponent';
$: componentConstructorClass = 
       componentConstructorName === 'testComponent'
     ? testComponent
     : someDefaultComponent
```

or perhaps with a switch statement

```js
let componentContructorName = 'testComponent';
$: componentConstructorClass = (() => switch(componentConstructorName) {
     case 'testComponent': return TestComponent;
     case 'testComponent2': return TestComponent2;
     default: someDefaultComponent;
})();
```

Comment: Yup, the switch is what I did initially. I'm going to put an request on GitHub for the community to discuss then. I think it would be a useful thing to do.

Comment: Oh boy, it's such a shame, that [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io) is pretty much dead. Once you worked with Aurelia, stuff like this ^ feels a bit cumbersome... 

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution, which is quite Vuey, I think.

```
<script>
  import CompOne from './CompOne.svelte';
  import CompTwo from './CompTwo.svelte';
  import CompThree from './CompThree.svelte';


  const components = { CompOne, CompTwo, CompThree }
  let compConstrName = "CompOne";
</script>

<svelte:component this={components[compConstrName]} />
```